# Style orders details table in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am using WordPress 4.8.1 and using bridge theme. 
I am facing some problem regarding removing price from new order template email. 
I want to remove price column ,however I removed total and subtotal , but not getting anything to remove price column with products as going through files.

I have found this is coming from this code:

```
 <?php 
    echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
                'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                'show_image'    => false,
                'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
            ) ); ?>
```

In email-order-details.php template which I have copied to my child theme from woocommerce template folder.

But , how to customise this hook 'wc_get_email_order_items' or any other way to remove price?

This is what I have now:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated as I have spent so much hours finding solution for same.

Comment: Can't you just override the email template and remove the price column?

Comment: I have already overrided the template into my theme, but price coming from the code which I mentioned above , I can't find HTML  which I can remove to remove price column

Comment: You should search for the strings already showing up in the email right now within the theme. The email template should be present in the theme or the plugin itself. You will be able to override the template as required.

Comment: I have tried in all possible ways to search for nearby strings in the email, but no success, only thing that I found I can remove whole product list row by removing above mentioned code but not only price column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done [Overriding the following WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/):

1.Template `email/email-order-details.php`

- Where you will remove the block at line 38:

```html
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

- And here also, all this blocks at line 50 to 63 (to remove):

```html
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                ?><tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
```

2.Template `emails/email-order-items.php`.

- Where you will remove this block at line 59:

```html
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
```

So you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Reigel
Finally its done :-) Mistake That I was doing that that I was making changes for file email-order-items.php under folder "Plain" in Emails folder .

Comment: Thankyou @LoicTheAztec for detailed description. :-)

Comment: @Harry It's the same thing, but may be not the same lines… You will need to check and try yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You have two files to copy, `email-order-details.php` and `email-order-items.php`.
These two files contains what you want to be removed. `email-order-details.php` has the `<th>` tag or the header of the table. And `email-order-items.php` has the `<td>` tags. Please check these files out.